# mobx computed function not re-running when observable value is updated in test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, mobx

I am attempting to write a unit test for mobx-based reaction. For some reason, when the `@observable` value is updated in an `@action`, the `@computed` function does not re-run as you'd expect.

Code:

**STORE**

```
class NameStore {
    @observable name;

    @action setName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**COMPONENT 1**

```
@observer
class Name {
    @computed get name() {
        if (this.props.nameStore.name) {
            return `${this.props.nameStore.name} is awesome!`;
        }

        return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="name">
                {this.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**COMPONENT 2**

```
@observer
class Name {
    setName() {
        this.props.nameStore.setName(this.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.setName.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" ref={input => this.name = input} />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

**TEST**

```
define('Name component', () => {
    let markup;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const nameStore = new NameStore();
        markup = mount(
            <div>
                <Component1 nameStore={nameStore} />
                <Component2 nameStore={nameStore} />
            </div>
        );
    });

    it('should re-render name when updated', (done) => {
        expect(markup.find('.name').text()).to.be.blank;

        markup.find('form input').first().value = "john";
        markup.find('form').simulate('submit');

        expect(markup.find('.name').text()).to.equal("john is awesome")
    });
});
```

For some reason, in the test, the actual value of `{this.name}` in `Component1` remains unchanged even though I'm able to verify that the `setName` function in the store is being called properly and with the correct value.

Any help as to why `Component1` is not re-rendering would be much appreciated.

Also, this is a contrived example as the actual example is proprietary..so forgive me if this example feels dumb :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are few mistakes:

- Neither of the components extends `React.Component`
- `@computed` should be in the store
- `input` should bind to `onChange` and updates its `value`
- Browser may complain `input` value is undefined. It's better to set it to empty string.
- `input` value is in `event.target.value`, `ref={input => this.name = input}` will assign `this.name` to the html component.
- The rule of thumb when deal with form is to call`event.preventDefault()`

The code below is a completed working example based on your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

class NameStore {
  @observable name = '';

  @action
  setName = name => {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @computed
  get awesomeName() {
    return this.name ? `${this.name} is awesome!` : '';
  }
}

@observer
class NameField extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { nameStore } = this.props;
    return <div className="name"> {nameStore.awesomeName} </div>;
  }
}

@observer
class NameInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { nameStore } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={nameStore.name}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }

  onChange = e => {
    const { nameStore } = this.props;
    nameStore.setName(e.target.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

@observer
class App extends React.Component {
  nameStore = new NameStore();

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NameField nameStore={this.nameStore} />
        <NameInput nameStore={this.nameStore} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Extra note: Since the arrow function has been used, I don't have to call `.bind(this)`.